# IPhone - animate the superview only

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

in my application i have a UIView (myView) , with some subviews. What i want to do is commit some kind of animation to practically hide myView , but keep it's subviews unaffected in the same place. The following code as expected affects both myView and its subviews :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
CGAffineTransform transformView =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-500, 0);
[myView setTransform:transformView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Is there any way to prevent the subviews from animating ?

You help is much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you create two subviews? One you attach subviews to and one that you use to animate out.

Answer (score 0):

No is the short answer to your question. You can think of a superView as a big box that has smaller boxes inside (subviews). If you hide the big box you also are hiding boxes inside it.